# ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar una función después de subir una imagen a Firebase?

Tags: firebase, angular

Estoy trabajando con Angular2 y tengo un servicio el cual sube una imagen a Firebase sin problema. El método para subir la imagen lo mando a llamar desde un componente. Quiero ejecutar una función **después de que la imagen haya sido subida con éxito**.

```
this._registroImg.cargarImagenesFirebase( this.archivos );

console.log('Ejecutar después de subir la imagen');
```

Dentro del método `cargarImagenesFirebase` tengo lo siguiente:

```
cargarImagenesFirebase( imagenes:FileItem[] ) {
  const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

  let item: FileItem = imagenes[0];

  const uploadTask: firebase.storage.UploadTask =
                storageRef.child(`${ this.CARPETA_IMAGENES }/${ item.nombreArchivo }`).put( item.archivo );

  uploadTask.on( firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
    ( snapshot: firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot ) => item.progreso = ( snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes ) * 100,
    ( error ) => console.error('Error al subir', error),
    () => {
      console.log('Imagen cargada correctamente');
      item.url = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
      item.estaSubiendo = false;
      this.guardarImagen({
        nombre: item.nombreArchivo,
        url: item.url
      });
    }
  )
}
```

El problema que tengo es que en la consola me imprime

```
Ejecutar después de subir la imagen

Imagen cargada correctamente
```

Mi pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo controlar el que una instrucción se ejecute después de que la primera termine? Ya que tengo la de subir la imagen a firebase antes del console.log, pero éste se ejecuta antes de que la función de firebase terminé de cargar el archivo e imprima que ya terminó.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar algo como esto:

```
cargarImagenesFirebase( imagenes:FileItem[] ) {   const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

  let item: FileItem = imagenes[0];

  const uploadTask: firebase.storage.UploadTask =
                storageRef.child(`${ this.CARPETA_IMAGENES }/${ item.nombreArchivo }`).put( item.archivo );

  uploadTask.on( firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
    ( snapshot: firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot ) => item.progreso = ( snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes ) * 100,
    ( error ) => console.error('Error al subir', error),
    () => {
      console.log('Imagen cargada correctamente');
      item.url = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
      item.estaSubiendo = false;
      this.guardarImagen({
        nombre: item.nombreArchivo,
        url: item.url
      });
      console.log('Ejecutar después de subir la imagen');
    }   ) }
```

Lo que haces es imprimir por consola cuando llama a ese servicio, y no cuando finaliza la carga de la imagen.